# How to make the module Node Embed work for any content type?

Tags: nodes

I have installed [Node Embed](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_embed) and created a content type called Text Page, and it works very well to embed nodes of all kind.

But I also have a content type called Article and there, no kind of node will be embedded.....I only get the [[(nid:number)]]. Both content types have the text field called: body; which is the long text and summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!! The body text was rendered through a view, and therefore it did not show the node embed content! So I changed it to "Node being viewed" Body....and there it was :)